# .Net Framework 4.8 MVC - ${aspnet-TraceIdentifier} is always empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, logging, nlog

In my .Net 4.8 MVC application I'm trying to write logs with NLog. One of the field is traceId - ${aspnet-TraceIdentifier}, which suppose to be supported by NLog.Web.

So I followed the [documentation](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web#aspnet-non-core) and installed:

- NLog v4.7.6
- NLog.Extensions.Logging v1.6.5
- NLog.Web v4.9.3

I placed my NLog.config in project's directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<nlog autoReload="true"
      xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      throwExceptions="true"
      internalLogLevel="trace"
      internalLogFile="c:\test\internal-nlog.txt">
  <targets>
    <target name="ws" xsi:type="WebService"  protocol="JsonPost"
            url="https://log-api.com/log/v1">
      <parameter name="time" layout="${date}" />
      <parameter name="level" layout="${level:upperCase=true}"/>
      <parameter name="message" layout="${message}" />
      <parameter name="host" layout="${machinename}" />
      <parameter name="threadid" layout="${threadid}" />
      <parameter name="ActivityId" layout="${activityId}" />
      <parameter name="processId" layout="${processId}" />
      <parameter name="threadid" layout="${threadid}" />
      <parameter name="event-properties" layout="${all-event-properties}" />
      <parameter name="exception" layout="${exception}" />
      <parameter name="traceId" layout="${aspnet-TraceIdentifier}" />
      <parameter name="environment" layout="Production" />
      <parameter name="serviceName" layout="company-api2222222" />
      <parameter name="session" layout="${aspnet-session}"/>
      <parameter name="sessionId" layout="${aspnet-sessionid}"/>
      <header name="X-License-Key" layout="${environment:LICENSE_KEY}"/>
    </target>
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="ws" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

According to the documentation, further configuration is not needed:
"Simply install the package. NLog will detect the extension automatically."

So, inside my controller I simply getting current class logger and logging:

```
NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Info("Hello World");
```

But unfortunately, ${aspnet-TraceIdentifier} value is empty, and the worst thing is that I cannot find any documentation about how to make it works.

I tried to put extensions tag above targets in NLog.config file

```
<extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web"/>
</extensions>
```

and even tried this as well:

```
<extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
</extensions>
```

But nothing changed. Can anyone help? There is something that I am missing? maybe a configuration problem after all?

Comment: See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/4217

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear if you're using ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core.

So an answer for both:

### ASP.NET (non core)

For ASP.NET you should use `<add assembly="NLog.Web"/>` and the NLog.Web package

- For ASP.NET with IIS needs IIS ETW feature enabled: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/httpTracing/ (IIS7 - Win2008)

internally `HttpWorkerRequest.RequestTraceIdentifier` will be used.

#### ASP.NET Core

For ASP.NET Core you should use `<add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>` and the NLog.Web.AspNetCore package

NLog uses these for the traceindentifier:

- ASP.NET Core 3-5: use `System.Diagnostics.Activity.Current.Id` (default) or  `HttpContext.TraceIdentifier`
- ASP.NET Core 1+2: `HttpContext.TraceIdentifier`
- For ASP.NET Core 3-5 you maybe need ignoreActivityId. e.g. `${aspnet-TraceIdentifier:ignoreActivityId=true}` - if true - `HttpContext.TraceIdentifier` will be used instead of `System.Diagnostics.Activity.Current.Id`